# pgfgantt: How to adjust \gantttitle width same as chart width?

Tags: width, pgfgantt, adjustwidth

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate]{2019-01-01}{2019-02-15}
        \gantttitle{TITLE}{30} \\
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**The question:**

How can I automatically adjust the width of the `\gantttitle` to the same width as the chart itself? Messing around with absolute (incremental) values like `30` does not seem to make a big sense - I guess there is some better solution available?

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command that returns the range, and use it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\makeatletter
\def\ganttrange{\the\numexpr1+\the\gtt@endjulian-\the\gtt@startjulian\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate]{2019-01-01}{2019-02-15}
        \gantttitle{TITLE}{\ganttrange} \\
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]